# Component definition - Missing display name error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, grafana, arrow-functions, monaco-editor

I'm trying to build a [custom panel option editor](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/custom-panel-option-editors/#custom-panel-option-editors) in web app called Grafana, but am running into an error I suspect is no more than a React syntax issue.

`195:15 error Component definition is missing display name react/display-name`

```js
export const optionsBuilder = (builder: PanelOptionsEditorBuilder<SVGOptions>) => {
  return builder
    .addBooleanSwitch({
      category: ['SVG Document'],
      path: 'svgAutoComplete',
      name: 'Enable SVG AutoComplete',
      description: 'Enable editor autocompletion, optional as it can be buggy on large documents',
    })
    .addCustomEditor({
      category: ['SVG Document'],
      path: 'svgSource',
      name: 'SVG Document',
      description: `Editor for SVG Document, while small tweaks can be made here, we recommend using a dedicated 
        Graphical SVG Editor and simply pasting the resulting XML here`,
      id: 'svgSource',
      defaultValue: props_defaults.svgNode,
      editor: (props) => {
        const grafanaTheme = config.theme.name;
        return (
          <MonacoEditor
            language="xml"
            theme={grafanaTheme === 'Grafana Light' ? 'vs-light' : 'vs-dark'}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}
          />
        );
      },
    })
};
```

> To use a custom panel option editor, use the addCustomEditor on the OptionsUIBuilder object in your module.ts file. Configure the editor to use by setting the editor property to the SimpleEditor component.

The [tutorial](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/custom-panel-option-editors/#custom-panel-option-editors) in the Grafana Docs explains more about what I'm doing, but I believe the issue is just with the arrow function I use at **line 195**.

Is there a different way I should be retrieving my `editor` property?

Comment: Please add code instead of images.

Comment: Please convert your image into a code snippet. As to your question. Convert the `(props) => {` arrow function into `function myNamedFunction(props) {` and that should solve the linting issue